# Advice On How to Backup Wordpress

Tags: security, hosting, backup, management

I have my site hosted with Cloudways and am using ManageWP to manage the site.  I am wondering about backup options.

Cloudways backs up the server and has an option to restore a particular app on that server (so if one site goes down and the others are fine, I can restore just that site).

ManageWP has automatic backups (either once a month free or more often for $1.00/month).  I am considering the $1.00/month option.

Then there are also plugins -- like UpdraftPlus (which would be the backup plugin I would use).

I am wondering the pros and cons of each option.  For example, I like using as few plugins as possible for performance and other reasons.  On the other hand, UpdraftPlus is basically free (small charge for the server usage).

I'm also wondering if some combination of the above is a good idea, or if that is overkill.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I'd do both. $1/month is a bargain, especially if that includes restores. But, I'd also do my own backup with something like UpdraftPlus or BackWPup to a Dropbox or Google Drive account just for added peace of mind.

Comment: @PeterHvD Thanks.  Would you also do the server backups?  I like the idea of redundancy, I'm just wondering when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I back up my site with a plugin and don’t rely on my web host provider to create backups. ManageWP is a good option for website backups. However, if you need to upload your backups to own cloud storage (like Amazon S3, Dropbox) from ManageWP, you have to pay the extra fee for that ($0.13/GB). If you are running a large website and back up it each 8 or 12 hours or daily, this will cost more money. Plus, many free WordPress backup plugins out there are available to use. But you have to carefully choose one, due to some freemium plugins lock the restore feature. Only [Updraftplus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) and [WPvivid Backup/Restore](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpvivid-backuprestore/) cover both backup and restore features in their free version. They both supports to create manual and scheduled backups and allow you to back up to the commonly used cloud storage. The scheduled backups and One-click restore give you peace of mind when you are facing data loss someday. If you don’t need extra features, the free version of both plugins can suite your needs.